# angular 9, TypeError: require is not a function when compiling (angular universal)

Tags: angular, angular-universal, formidable

I am trying to build a web app using the latest angular and universal.
I added the :

```
npm i formidable
```

in my app and when I try to build, I get first the warning :

> WARNING in ./node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js 1:43-50
>   Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Then right after that, i get the compiling error

> /Users/user/sos/dist/application/server/main.js:1
>   !function(e,a){for(var i in a)e[i]=a[i]}(exports,function(modules){var installedModules={},installedChunks={1:0};function **webpack_require**(moduleId){if(installedModules[moduleId])return installedModules[moduleId].exports;var module=installedModules[moduleId]={i:moduleId,l:!1,exports:{}};return modules[moduleId].call(module.exports,module,module.exports,**webpack_require**),module.l=!0,module.exports}return **webpack_require**.e=function requireEnsure(chunkId){if(0!==installedChunks[chunkId]){var chunk=require("./"+({0:"contact-contact-module",2:"pages-populate-populate-module"}[chunkId]||chunkId)+".js"),moreModules=chunk.modules,chunkIds=chunk.ids;for(var moduleId in moreModules)modules[moduleId]=moreModules[moduleId];for(var i=0;iwebpack_require.m=modules,**webpack_require**.c=installedModules,**webpack_require**.d=function(exports,name,getter){**webpack_require**.o(exports,name)||
>
> TypeError: require is not a function

I have been trying to find a solution but none works, what can cause this error?

If I remove the formidable package, this error goes away but I need formidable AND file upload

Comment: what was your solution?